# The main thread locked when fetching images from parse with semaphore

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios4, semaphore

I have a very big problem. I use Parse cloud system. When i fetch images with using "dispatch_semaphore" from parse, the main thread is locked. However, i think, i don't use main thread when fetching images. Normally, the task should be executed order by section A,B,C then D but app locked in section B.

Thanks.

```
    let semaphore1:dispatch_semaphore_t = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    let semaphore2:dispatch_semaphore_t = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

    let userquery = PFQuery(className: "_User")

    userquery.findObjectsInBackground().continueWithSuccessBlock { (task) -> AnyObject? in

        let results = task.result as! NSArray

        for objectarray  in results
        {
            let object = objectarray as! PFObject
            let username = object["username"] as! String
            let userpictureThumbnail = object["userPhotoThumbnail"] as! PFFile
            userpictureThumbnail.getDataInBackground().continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task2) -> AnyObject? in

                let result = task2.result as! NSData
                let image = UIImage(data: result)
                let imageThumbnail = image

                // Section C-) Below codes must be executed but main thread is locked by Section B.
                Model.sharedInstance.friendsPictureModel.addItem(username,FriendImageThumbnail:imageThumbnail!)

                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore2)
                return nil

            })

            // Section B-) Second, enter the  below code . And lock main thread then app freezed.
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore2, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore1)
        return nil 
    }

    // Section A-) When the block("userquery.findObjectsInBackground().continueWithSuccessBlock") is executed, enter the  below code firstly.
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore1, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

    // Section D-) Below codes must be executed in the last.
    self.collectionview.reloadData()
```

Comment: are you calling `dispatch_sempahore_wait` on main thread? If so, shouldn't you move it to a background thread if you don't want to block the main thread? as in, move he whole task (sempahore creation and waiting) to secondary thread.

Comment: Is there somewhere that recommends using semaphores? At just a surface level, I am not surprised that you have blocking on the main thread as that is what semaphores are designed to do. If you know the parse fetch is happening in the background, I would instead have my completion block do dispatch_async back onto the main thread calling `reloadData()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using semaphores here. Your section A is (presumably) running on the main thread, and the wait will cause it to block until the semaphore is signalled.

You could remove all the semaphore code and just dispatch `self.collectionview.reloadData()` onto the main thread in where semaphore2 is currently being signalled. However, you also have a problem that addItem is being called in the background, and it's probably not thread safe.

On the assumption that your example is a simplification of your specific problem, you probably have some separation between the viewController and userquery (let's call it `findTheObjects`. So at the moment you would have something like:

```
myObjectFinder.findTheObjects()
```

In this case, you should pass in your own completion block, along the lines of:

```
myObjectFinder.findTheObjects(completion: {
    (username, imageThumbnail?) -> Void in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // do something with the results like...
        Model.sharedInstance.friendsPictureModel.addItem(username,FriendImageThumbnail:theResults.imageThumbnail!)
        self.collectionview.reloadData()
    })
}
```

This completion block would then be called from your Section C.